# Suggestions for an algorithm which requires math functions

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers

I need some suggestions,here is my problem:
I have about 800 function names that I need to associate with a list of data couples 'a' and 'b' with 'a' and 'b' between 0 and 10 ,these couples must be generated by a math function.
A solution is to create a switch where I implement each function in a case but it's very tiring
So I thought of doing such a thing:

1. function_name='A_greater_B'
2. user_input=A>B
3. method getPairList(user_input)
4. foreach(couple of 'a' and 'b')
5. if(user_input)
6. insert_into_pair_list(couple)

Insert every conditions is a good compromise for me but I don't know how to implement line 5 in java.
Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. Can you give a concrete example?

Comment: Show us what have you done so far and tell us what are the specific problems you're having with your current implementation. Read carefully the http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: every function name must generate a subset taken from the set A={(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),....(10,10)} so if the function name is "a_equals_b" the subset is k={(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,10)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/)

So you can do something like this

```
import bsh.EvalError;
import bsh.Interpreter;
public class X {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws EvalError {
        Interpreter bsh = new Interpreter();
        String expr = "20>10";
        bsh.eval("boolean b="+expr);
        Boolean b = (Boolean)bsh.eval("b");
        System.out.println(b);
    }

}
```